# Folder not visible in shared directory but is accessible with direct UNC path

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, permissions, network-share

I have a shared Users directory that I access at the following UNC path:

`\\servername\Users`

Inside this directory each User in my company has a folder that they are allowed to store pretty much anything they want. The UNC path for each user is similar to the following:

`\\servername\Users\username$`

Each user folder is shared directly as well and I can also access each folder with the following path:

`\\servername\username$`

The server that hosts all of these folders and shares is running on Windows Server 2003.

I have one User, lets call him Joe, who has a folder in this share. Whenever I open the share `\\servername\Users` from a Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 machine I am unable to see his folder listed. However I am still able to directly access his folder with `\\servername\Users\Joe$` and `\\servername\Joe$`.

I do however see Joe's folder listed when I access the same shares from a Windows XP or Windows Server 2003 machine.

I have already double checked all of the share and security permissions on his folder and they are correct and match every other users folder.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you add the $ character to a share, it becomes a hidden share.  So if you have  `\\SERVER\Folder` and `\\SERVER\Folder1$` both with the same permissions, you will NOT be able to see `Folder1$` when you browse to `\\SERVER`.

The relevant MS knowledge base article is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314984) but the first line of the article:

> A hidden share is identified by a dollar sign ($) at the end of the share name. Hidden shares are not listed when you look through the shares on a computer or use the net view command.

Says it all.

**EDIT** Per our discussion below, the only solution I can think of is to delete/recreate the folder and see what happens.  I'm baffled as to what would cause the behavior otherwise.

Comment: That is interesting because all of my users shares are of this format and I can see there shares just fine.... Joe user is the only one I can not see using this method.

Comment: And also I can see Joe user's share from an XP or 2003 machine

Comment: So when you go to \\SERVER\Users and look at the properties of user TIM, who you are normally able to see, is his folder called TIM and shared as TIM$?

Comment: No user TIM's folder is called TIM$ and his share is TIM$

Comment: Then I am baffled, to be honest...  I don't know what would cause that behavior for one user, when the rest are fine, and other MS OSes can see it.  The best advice I can give at this point is delete and recreate the folder and see what happens.

Comment: I am thinking along the same lines as well. If you want to update your answer to reflect this I will accept. Thanks for your help.